# PHP GET [parameter] ulencode from an included php file with javascript

Tags: php, include

On `index.php` I'm using `downloadUrl` for a file called `data.php` in the same folder. (Which works as intended)

`$type = urlencode($_GET['type']);` WORKS on `index.php`
but NOT on `data.php`. It returns nothing when used there...

Comment: Are you getting value of "type" variable in included file?

Comment: can you please show your code how you using

Comment: `$_GET` is a super global, so it should be available on all included scripts.

Comment: sorry it was not by <?php include but by javascript. like this:downloadUrl("<?php echo $type; ?>data.php", function(data) {

Comment: what does javascript has to do with it?

Comment: can you show code ..you are trying ? because seems that type is not set in data.php or problem is at something else

Comment: yes i think u are right that it's not set. GET url worked for filename but im trying to make it quicker to add content to the site without needing to create new files just for the reason of getting the filename. I'll try to find the right bits of code to paste if that may solve it!

Comment: Thanks for all comments. I got it answered by looking at my other question i asked a long time ago which i now understood. I request the file with the parameters at the end!

Comment: @Algatella answer in other question isn't fool prof .. you know mysql_* function are deprecated check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189

Comment: Thanks! Im gonna change the code before i upgrade to 5.5 :)